# Adding a method to a function object at runtime

Tags: python, function, decorator

I read a question earlier asking if there was a `times` method in Python, that would allow a function to be called n times in a row.

Everyone suggested `for _ in range(n): foo()` but I wanted to try and code a different solution using a function decorator.

Here's what I have:

```
def times(self, n, *args, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(n):
        self.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

import new
def repeatable(func):
    func.times = new.instancemethod(times, func, func.__class__)

@repeatable
def threeArgs(one, two, three):
    print one, two, three

threeArgs.times(7, "one", two="rawr", three="foo")
```

When I run the program, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 244, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\py\repeatable.py", line 24, in 
    threeArgs.times(7, "one", two="rawr", three="foo")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'times'
```

So I suppose the decorator didn't work? How can I fix this?

Comment: This method seems to be less idiomatic and less simple than the one you are replacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your decorator should return the function object:

```
def repeatable(func):
    func.times = new.instancemethod(times, func, func.__class__)
    return func
```

Now it returns nothing, so you actually change threeArgs in a None

This is because this:

```
@decorator
def func(...):
    ...
```

is more or less the same as:

```
def func(...):
    ....
func = decorator(func)
```

Comment: awesome, I guess I should have figured... oh well, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return func` statement at the end of your `repeatable` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered not adding it to specific functions and instead allowing its use with *any* function?

```
def times(n, func, *args, **kwds):
  return [func(*args, **kwds) for _ in xrange(n)]
```

(I'm returning a list of return values, but you could write it to ignore them, similar to the for-loop you have in the question.)

Then where you would, with your version, use:

```
threeArgs.times(7, "one", two="rawr", three="foo")
```

You instead use:

```
times(7, threeArgs, "one", two="rawr", three="foo")
```